# Recorrer un Json con PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Necesito recorrer este JSON para extraer datos.
Necesito extraer el id del player en que su user sea null, pero no tengo manera.
Este es mi codigo:

```
curl_setopt($curlMercado, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curlMercado, CURLOPT_URL, $urlMercado);
curl_setopt($curlMercado, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curlMercado);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curlMercado);

print_r($result);
//Convertir el string que viene en json
$jsonPlayers = json_decode($result, true);  
foreach($jsonPlayers as $jugador['data']['sales']){
    if(isnull($jugador['user'])){
        print($jugador['id']);          
    }
```

Este el JSON:

> {
> "status":200,
> "data":{
> "status":{
> "balance":79549,
> "maximumBid":17264549
> },
> "sales":[
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":1000000,
> "player":{
> "id":58
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":690000,
> "player":{
> "id":874
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":420000,
> "player":{
> "id":1032
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":1190000,
> "player":{
> "id":1609
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":4130000,
> "player":{
> "id":1676
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":1370000,
> "player":{
> "id":1864
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":3630000,
> "player":{
> "id":2194
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":2490000,
> "player":{
> "id":6925
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":850000,
> "player":{
> "id":10117
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":150000,
> "player":{
> "id":11633
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":230000,
> "player":{
> "id":11639
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":2710000,
> "player":{
> "id":13664
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":150000,
> "player":{
> "id":17051
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":150000,
> "player":{
> "id":18252
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":150000,
> "player":{
> "id":18496
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":6580000,
> "player":{
> "id":18945
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":1160000,
> "player":{
> "id":19298
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":1340000,
> "player":{
> "id":19839
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":160000,
> "player":{
> "id":22687
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606975485,
> "until":1607061600,
> "price":150000,
> "player":{
> "id":22988
> },
> "user":null
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":3744000,
> "player":{
> "id":764
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":1368000,
> "player":{
> "id":1780
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":10284000,
> "player":{
> "id":1912
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":21804000,
> "player":{
> "id":2603
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":10944000,
> "player":{
> "id":5830
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":3588000,
> "player":{
> "id":6817
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":600000,
> "player":{
> "id":9700
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":612000,
> "player":{
> "id":10346
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":11928000,
> "player":{
> "id":15410
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":5628000,
> "player":{
> "id":15719
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":1548000,
> "player":{
> "id":16955
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":2784000,
> "player":{
> "id":17021
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":5844000,
> "player":{
> "id":22066
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> },
> {
> "date":1606890938,
> "until":1607063738,
> "price":1320000,
> "player":{
> "id":22724
> },
> "user":{
> "id":4142949
> }
> }
> ],
> "offers":[
> {
> "id":96538845,
> "amount":9072500,
> "created":1606889166,
> "until":1607061600,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 5830
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":1427238925,
> "amount":476700,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 10346
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":1482792901,
> "amount":9883200,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 15410
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":1731613993,
> "amount":1088600,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 22724
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":1942952313,
> "amount":1172900,
> "created":1606889166,
> "until":1607061600,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 1780
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":2026211965,
> "amount":8395800,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 1912
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":2149622738,
> "amount":4701300,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 15719
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":2219817302,
> "amount":3263700,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 764
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":3034085246,
> "amount":1223300,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 16955
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":3283405838,
> "amount":2405400,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 17021
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":3533292962,
> "amount":504300,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 9700
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":4084429058,
> "amount":19087600,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 2603
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":4180418774,
> "amount":2919700,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 6817
> ]
> },
> {
> "id":4274003870,
> "amount":4692200,
> "created":1606975485,
> "until":1607148000,
> "status":"waiting",
> "type":"purchase",
> "from":null,
> "to":{
> "id":4142949
> },
> "requestedPlayers":[
> 22066
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> }

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de esta forma, aqui obtienes el Id del player cuando user == null

```
$json  = '{ "status":200, "data":{ "status":{ "balance":79549, "maximumBid":17264549 }, "sales":[ { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":1000000, "player":{ "id":58 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":690000, "player":{ "id":874 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":420000, "player":{ "id":1032 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":1190000, "player":{ "id":1609 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":4130000, "player":{ "id":1676 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":1370000, "player":{ "id":1864 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":3630000, "player":{ "id":2194 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":2490000, "player":{ "id":6925 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":850000, "player":{ "id":10117 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":150000, "player":{ "id":11633 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":230000, "player":{ "id":11639 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":2710000, "player":{ "id":13664 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":150000, "player":{ "id":17051 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":150000, "player":{ "id":18252 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":150000, "player":{ "id":18496 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":6580000, "player":{ "id":18945 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":1160000, "player":{ "id":19298 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":1340000, "player":{ "id":19839 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":160000, "player":{ "id":22687 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606975485, "until":1607061600, "price":150000, "player":{ "id":22988 }, "user":null }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":3744000, "player":{ "id":764 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":1368000, "player":{ "id":1780 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":10284000, "player":{ "id":1912 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":21804000, "player":{ "id":2603 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":10944000, "player":{ "id":5830 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":3588000, "player":{ "id":6817 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":600000, "player":{ "id":9700 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":612000, "player":{ "id":10346 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":11928000, "player":{ "id":15410 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":5628000, "player":{ "id":15719 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":1548000, "player":{ "id":16955 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":2784000, "player":{ "id":17021 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":5844000, "player":{ "id":22066 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } }, { "date":1606890938, "until":1607063738, "price":1320000, "player":{ "id":22724 }, "user":{ "id":4142949 } } ], "offers":[ { "id":96538845, "amount":9072500, "created":1606889166, "until":1607061600, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 5830 ] }, { "id":1427238925, "amount":476700, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 10346 ] }, { "id":1482792901, "amount":9883200, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 15410 ] }, { "id":1731613993, "amount":1088600, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 22724 ] }, { "id":1942952313, "amount":1172900, "created":1606889166, "until":1607061600, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 1780 ] }, { "id":2026211965, "amount":8395800, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 1912 ] }, { "id":2149622738, "amount":4701300, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 15719 ] }, { "id":2219817302, "amount":3263700, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 764 ] }, { "id":3034085246, "amount":1223300, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 16955 ] }, { "id":3283405838, "amount":2405400, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 17021 ] }, { "id":3533292962, "amount":504300, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 9700 ] }, { "id":4084429058, "amount":19087600, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 2603 ] }, { "id":4180418774, "amount":2919700, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 6817 ] }, { "id":4274003870, "amount":4692200, "created":1606975485, "until":1607148000, "status":"waiting", "type":"purchase", "from":null, "to":{ "id":4142949 }, "requestedPlayers":[ 22066 ] } ] } }';
  $json = json_decode($json,true);
  $array=array();
  foreach($json['data']['sales'] as $j){
      if($j['user'] == null){
        array_push($array,array(
          'id' => $j['player']['id']
        ));
      }
  }
  print_r($array);
```

Resultado del print_r() 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi varible $json es tu variable $result reemplaza y tendras los id del player cuando user = null

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias Gerardo :)